# How to set up a real-time controller with reinforcement learning algorithms

Tags: tensorflow, real-time

I'm trying to control an actual robot manipulator using reinforcement learning. For reinforcement learning, I'm using Google tensorflow.

To control a robot manipulator, I need my controller to have real-time capability. However, as far as I know, python and thus tensorflow is not real-time friendly. I want to control the robot at about 100 ~ 1000 Hz.

I've considered implementing my own reinforcement learning algorithm in C++, but it would be too much work, and take too much time.

Is there anyway of using Tensorflow reinforcement learning algorithms in C++? Or, is there any other way of implementing reinforcement learning algorithm to a C++ real-time controller?

Any help would be appreciated.

Sincerely,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why Tensorflow is not good for real-time control since a TF model is not subject to the limitations of the Python interpreter.
In case you find that standard TF is not fast enough you can also have a look at TF-lite: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite.